# How can I pass iterators as function arguments?

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm working on some c++ problems from a book and my task is to count number occurrences in a list. The task can be solved with just one iterator walking on each item of the list. However, I've done this before with other other task and I'm trying something different with this one. The idea is basically to use two iterators that increase a counter whenever the step on a value until they meet each other. I'm done with that for just the first value of the list but now I want to do it for the rest of the different numbers of the list. The main problem currently is that I can't find out why the programs hangs when I pass an iterator as an argument since creating the `start` iterator within the `findNumberOccurrences` and initialize it with the `input.begin()` value doesn't have any problem if that makes sense.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <list>
  
int findNumberOccurences(std::list<int> input, std::list<int>::iterator& start) {
    std::cout << *start << '\n';
    std::list<int>::iterator end = input.end();
    int count = 1;
   
    while (std::distance(input.begin(), start) != std::distance(input.begin(), end)) {
        while (*end != *start) {
            --end;
        }
 
        ++count;
        ++start;

        if (std::distance(input.begin(), start) == std::distance(input.begin(), end)) {
            break;
        }
 
        while (*start != *end) {
            std::cout << *start << '\n';
            ++start;
        }
 
        ++count;
        --end; 
    } 

    return count;
} 

int main() {
    std::list<int> input = {3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2};
    std::list<int>::iterator start = input.begin();
    int count = findNumberOccurences(input, start);
    std::cout << count << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I've written some cout logs within each while loop but I don't anything that gives me a clue about what's going on. Weird thing is that my terminal cursor keeps blinking without throwing exception like when having an infinite loop.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong please?

Cheers!

Comment: You cannot dereference `end` when it's still `list.end()`...I'd also suggest a debugger.

Comment: `end` is an iterator of a parameter of the function, which is passed by copy, so different than the list from `main`.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMM! I've just found the answer. Turns out that I need to pass input list as a reference `int findNumberOfOccurences(std::list<int> &input, std::list<int>::iterator & start)` o make it work. On the other hand, I want to take your suggestion regarding using a debugger. Currently, I'm using vim and it's been fantastic but I've not been able to set a c++ debugger for it. Do you know an article I can read by any chance?

Comment: Given that `std::distance` with bidirectional iterators is `O(n)`, the shown code will eventually end in tears.

Comment: Passing by reference is the fix for my comment, you still have issue spotted by chrisMM:  `while (*end != *start)`

Comment: Not sure about what you try to count...

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for the comment! I'm count the number of occurrences of each number in a list. Currently, I'm just working with the first number of the list

Comment: Thanks @SamVarshavchik! I'm trying to approach the problem in different ways. This code mightn't be a good idea but I'm just exploring. Could you go deeper with "Given that `std::distance` with bidrectional iterators is `0(n)` (I guess this means big O notation where it takes as many iterations as items in the list right?)

Comment: `while (std::distance(input.begin(), start) != std::distance(input.begin(), end))` might simply be `while (start != end)`

Comment: Yep @Jarod42! I did that, but I ended up with an infinite loop, I'm gonna double check that though

Comment: Just checked that `while(start !=end)` works and it's indeed much better than the original statement. I'd like to perform some test cause I remember I had some issue with a few use cases.

Comment: [Fixed version](https://godbolt.org/z/b6T7f9ooj).

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42! I'm gonna checkout const_iterators in the reference manual. But I understand that they fix what @ChrisMM pointed out.

Comment: Yes. And this is inside another `O(n)` loop. Which makes the whole thing `O(n^2)` which, hopefully, will make it more clear why it will end in tears.

Comment: Take a look at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count , that algorithm should solve your entire problem. 

Then I can recommend, to nearly always pass iterators or pointer like types by non const value and every object, which is used read only by const reference.

Also, your loop can be way simpler, by using a for loop and moving exit predicates and end statements into the loop header.

Comment: Thanks guys! This is insightful. I'm now aware that this code isn't a good idea. Originally I solved the issue in a very linear conventional way so to say but since I watched this talk (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_M4o0ExLQCs) I've tried to explore new territories instead of going for the way to solve the task I'm used to.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've just found the answer to this question. Basically, I must pass a reference of the list as a function argument like this:

```cpp
int findNumberOfOccurrences(std::list<int> &input, std::list<int>::iterator &start)
```

I did that intuitively but I want to know why this solves the problem so I'm gonna read about references. If anyone wants add anything to the answer, please by all means.

Comment: The problem without using a reference is, that you will create a copy of your list, but using the old iterator of the original list. Therefore, the begin iterator will never be compatible to the new list, resulting in undefined behavior (might be always false or crash for example) at the moment you compare the end iterator of the new list, with the iterator of the original list.

Comment: Thanks @FabianKeßler! It makes now,  I didn't realize that compatibility problem with my arguments. Learned something new today \m/

Answer (score 0):

Passing the container by reference "fixes" the immediate problem in the code, but the code itself is flawed. When you're dealing with iterators you don't need the underlying container; indeed, there often **isn't** an underlying container. That's the point of iterators: they provide an abstraction that gives your code more flexibility.

In this case, just write the function to take two iterators:

```
int findNumberOccurences(std::list<int>::iterator first,
    std::list<int>::iterator last) {
    // code goes here
}
```

It's not clear to me what the code in the question is actually doing, so I haven't reproduced it. But in general, you can use `first` and `last` as the two ends of the data sequence and manipulate them appropriately.

```
while (first != last) {
    // do something with *first
    ++first;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PeteBecker! I get what you mean, iterators are born from an already declare list so there's no point using the input list itself. I'm gonna try your code later to fully understand the concept.